# Sprintf to concat string

Tags: c, mpi, printf, mpf

I have a string which I need to concat some data onto the end. My problem is that each time the loop goes round I get previous loop data on the end of my string. 
e.g data

1st loop iteration 
   1234@3
   2nd loop iteration
   3462@3@124
   3rd loop iteration
   3676@3@124@67
   and so on..

what i need to do is receive the string and some data to the end, set the string for each loop iteration.

```
if(rank == 0)
{


    char *recv_str = malloc(PRECISION);
    int retVal = -10;
    int len;
    long exp;
    char *str_exp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    char *deli = "@";


    for(i=1; i<= size - 1 ; i++)
    {

       MPI_Recv(&exp,1,MPI_LONG,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
       MPI_Recv(&len,1,MPI_INT,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
       MPI_Recv(recv_str,len, MPI_CHAR, i, 1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &status); 

          sprintf(str_exp, "%lu", exp); 
          sprintf(recv_str + strlen(recv_str), deli);
          sprintf(recv_str + strlen(recv_str),str_exp);              


       retVal = mpf_set_str(pi_ret, recv_str, 10); 
       //printf("string = %s \n", recv_str);
       //printf("\nvalid? %d length %d\n", retVal, len);
       //printf("str_exp  = %s \n", str_exp);
       mpf_add(pi, pi, pi_ret);
       //printf("\nsize of %lu \n", strlen(recv_str));

    }
```

Comment: you need to allocate the memory for the string before writing to it!

Comment: @musicmatze, it does (malloc)

Comment: @AlterMann where? It does `malloc(8)`. That's enough for 8 characters, but I guess the OP wants to concat much more! And it does `malloc(PRECISION)`. What this constant exactly is,... don't know. Is it enough? Nowere mentioned!

Comment: You can use `realloc()` to the correct size and `strcat()` to append the string.

Comment: no, `malloc(8)` is enough for 7 characters (when using `sprintf`), and yes, you guess ... Is it enough? Nowere mentioned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
char * recv_str = malloc(PRECISION * sizeof(*recv_str)); /* Make sure PRECISION is large enough!!! */
...
char str_exp[32] = ""; /* Make it's large enough to hold the decimal representaion of a long. */
char * deli = "@";

if (NULL == recv_str)
{
  perror("malloc() failed for recv_str");
  assert(1);
}

for(i=1; i<= size - 1 ; i++)
{
  strcpy(recv_str, ""); /* Reset the "string" to "empty" before each iteration! */

  ...

  sprintf(str_exp, "%ld", exp); 

  assert(sizeof(recv_str) <= (strlen(recv_str) + strlen(deli)));
  strcat(recv_str, deli);

  assert(sizeof(recv_str) <= (strlen(recv_str) + strlen(str_exp)));
  strcat(recv_str, str_exp); 

  ...
}

free(recv_str);
```

---

**Update:**

As it showed that initialsing `recv_str` to `0`-length by doing

```
strcpy(recv_str, "");
```

did not solve the problem, as it most probably only sets the "string"'s 1<sup>st</sup> byte to `NUL`/`'\0'`, the more radical approach needed to be taken to clear out the whole "string" with `0`s by doing:

```
memset(recv_str, 0, PRECISION * sizeof(*recv_str));
```

Comment: It must be to do with something with MPI, as I am printing the string after strcpy which shows "" as expected, but once the string is received I print again and it stil has @123@34@456 from each iteration. I have printed the string being sent and it does not contain this.

Comment: I did. Its got me stumped

Comment: this is what im doing to check string.. strcpy(recv_str, "");
        //printf("string = %s \n", recv_str);
           MPI_Recv(&exp,1,MPI_LONG,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
           MPI_Recv(&len,1,MPI_INT,i,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
           MPI_Recv(recv_str,len, MPI_CHAR, i, 1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &status); 
     printf("\n string = %s \n", recv_str);

Comment: @Simon: Try a `memset(recv_str, 0, <however as many bytes you have allocated to recv_str, probabaly PRECISION>)` instread of `strcpy(recv_str, "")`.